# Insert Additional Condition in LINQ

Tags: sql-server, linq

I am modifying a LINQ query in SQL Server 2014, but I have never used the syntax:

```
if (!UserAccessMatrixSession.HasRole(Session, Constant.ROLE_STAFF))
{
    if (country != 0 )
    {
        ViewData["Employees"] = (from staff in db.Staffs
                                 from jobinfo in db.JobInfo
                                        .Where(x => x.staff_id == staff.StaffID)
                                        .OrderByDescending(x => x.jobinfo_id).Take(1)
                                 orderby staff.Alias
                                 select new { staff, jobinfo }).Where(x => x.jobinfo.location == country)
                                 .Select(x => x.staff).ToList();
    }
    else
    {
        ViewData["Employees"] = (from staff in db.Staffs
                                 orderby staff.Alias
                                 select staff).ToList();
    }
}
```

I would like to insert an additional condition as follows:

`where jobinfo.last_date == null OR DateTime.Now < jobinfo.last_date`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you would want to add that `where` clause into where you are selecting from the job info

```
if (!UserAccessMatrixSession.HasRole(Session, Constant.ROLE_STAFF))
{
    if (country != 0 )
    {
        ViewData["Employees"] = (from staff in db.Staffs
                                 from jobinfo in db.JobInfo
                                        .Where(x => x.staff_id == staff.StaffID)
                                        .OrderByDescending(x => x.jobinfo_id).Take(1)
                                 orderby staff.Alias
                                 select new { staff, jobinfo }).Where(x => x.jobinfo.location == country 
                             /* last_date null or UtcNow < last_date*/ && (x.jobinfo.last_date == null || DateTime.UtcNow < jobinfo.last_date))
                                 .Select(x => x.staff).ToList();
    }
    else
    {
        ViewData["Employees"] = (from staff in db.Staffs
                                 orderby staff.Alias
                                 select staff).ToList();
    }
}
```